# php, simplexml_load_file, check if <media:group> exist

Tags: php, rss

I use `$rss = simplexml_load_file($xmlurl);`
and then: `foreach ($rss->channel->item as $feed_item){...`

going forward to collect data.

I use `$namespaces = $feed_item->getNamespaces(true);` and then read `<media:group>`

the problem came up with a `<media:group>` Some of the `$feed_item` have it, some don't.

In that case, I use:

```
if ( !isset($feed_item->children($namespaces['media'])->group) ){ continue;}
```

because I don't want to use that item
and that work but throw me an error: `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: media in...`
which I terminated with `error_reporting(0);` at the top of the script.

Is there is the way to accomplish that task without error at all?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($namespaces);`

Comment: When the result is correct I get: array(1) { ["media"]=> string(29) "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" }  and on error: array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@executable**, I got a clue what to do.
After `var_dump($namespaces);` I've figured it out that the `$namespaces` is a simple `array`.

So, the answer will be:

```
if (!array_key_exists("media", $namespaces)) do_what_you_have_to_do;
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't rely on a namespace prefix like `media` being the same in different documents, or even different versions of the same software; the namespace URI is the part that's guaranteed to stay the same - in this case `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss`.

Comment: Shure thing but in my case I first manually check the feed to see present namespaces and then choose what to use.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be improved in two ways:

```
 $namespaces = $feed_item->getNamespaces(true);
 if ( !isset($feed_item->children($namespaces['media'])->group) ){ continue; }
```

Firstly, the `children` method has an `isPrefix` flag, so you can provide the prefix directly without the intermediate array:

```
 if ( !isset($feed_item->children('media', true)->group) ){ continue; }
```

Secondly, relying on the prefix in the first place is dangerous: there's no guarantee that two different feeds, or even different versions of the same software, will map the same prefix to the same namespace.

Instead, you should directly hard-code the namespace URI in your code, in this case `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss`:

```
 if ( !isset($feed_item->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss')->group) ){ continue; }
```

Since namespace URIs can be quite long and hard to read, you might want to define this as a constant in your code so you can refer to it by a name that's meaningful to you:

```
const XMLNS_YAHOO_MEDIA = 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss';     
if ( !isset($feed_item->children(XMLNS_YAHOO_MEDIA)->group) ){ continue; }
```